# Get variables in two separate lines

Tags: command-line

I have the file ole.txt:

```
A   B   C
1   2   3
a   b   c
11  22  33
```

with option A:

```
cat ole.txt | sed -n -e 1p -e 3p
```

we get:

```
A   B   C
a   b   c
```

with option B:

```
sox=$(cat ole.txt | sed -n -e 1p -e 3p)
echo $sox
```

we get:

```
A B C a b c
```

How can I change the code in option B to get the result in option A (the result as 2 rows)?

Comment: You forgot the quotes around `$sox` (and you used `echo` which you shouldn't for arbitrary data). Try `printf '%s\n' "$sox"`. Also it doesn't make sense to concatenate a single file, use `sox=$(sed -ne 1p -e 3p ole.txt)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Quotes* is the answer.

```
echo "$sox"
```

should do the trick. If you don't want a newline at the end, you can use

```
printf "$sox"
```

Taking a look at the [Linux Documentation Project's page on quoting variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html) might help you understand better what weak quotes, i.e. **"**, entail.